# Woocommerce - Group by first letter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display the products in my Shop page like that:

A
Asd
Asddd

B
Beer
Bear

and so on. I managed to do this for the categories by overriding and using the **woocommerce_output_product_categories** action and for them it works, but I want to do this for the products as well(since Woocommerce gives you the option to show products or categories in the shop page). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be so many possible solutions. But for me this can be done like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'wc_shop_loop', 30 );
function wc_shop_loop() {
    global $product, $last_title_first_letter_95845949545454;
    $title = $product->get_title();

    if ( $last_title_first_letter_95845949545454 !== $title[0] ) {
        $last_title_first_letter_95845949545454 = $title[0];
        woocommerce_product_loop_end(); // let's close the loop.
        echo '<h3>'.$last_title_first_letter_95845949545454. '</h3>'; // add a letter heading.
        woocommerce_product_loop_start(); // open a new loop start.
    }
}
```

Tested to work on shop page and product category page.

[image: reigelgallarde.me]

You will need to work on its css.

Comment: I understand the code and tried something similar, but nothing changes. Are you sure this overrides it for the Shop page?

Comment: The screenshot is there as proof. That's the shop page.

Comment: I think my theme overrides it somewhere else :/

Comment: you may check `yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php`

Comment: Looks like it wasn't using the woocommerce_shop_loop, and that's why there was no change. I fixed it now. Thank you for your code so much!